# Odd white space on smaller screens (non-responsive site)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

If you take my current site below 1224px resolution and scroll to the right, there is just white space where there should be content.

http://opennetsummit.wpengine.com/conference/

What am I missing?

Comment: Look at the .container class. You have set "width: 1224px !important;" to it many times throughout your style.css

Comment: Yes, but that's the size that I want : ) The client specifically asked for a non-responsive site.

Comment: Maybe setting min-width: 1224px to the body could achieve what you want

Comment: @AugustoBarreto that worked perfectly! If you want to create an "answer" i'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .container class has a fixed width of 1224px and (according to the comments) you don't need your site to be responsive below 1224px width, so the easiest solution is to set min-width: 1224px to the body element of your document.